# Difference between sum of two columns is not equal?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have two columns: A&B.

- In one calculation I summed up each column then calculated the difference: SUM(A)- SUM(B) and got **~16M**
- In another calculation I found the difference between each line item and then summed that. So essentially SUM OF (A1-B1),(A2-B2),etc. Where I dragged the subtraction formula down to the end of the columns and just did the sum of that column. I got **~17M**

Why are the not equal?

Comment: Some sample data or a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Please share your file with the community.  With your Excel Spreadsheet, it´s easier to get faster feedback.

Comment: ^^^^^^ no do not share a file.  Links to files are short lived and will not help future readers.  Instead create a [mcve] with mock data that shows the error so we can replicate it.

Comment: My guess is that you have numbers stored as text interspersed with your data and as such the `SUM()` is ignoring them.  When you do `=A1-B1` it will convert the numbers stored as text to numbers but `SUM()` is designed to ignore any text.

Comment: @ScottCraner ah, i'm so stupid. i had some blanks that resulted in an error, but i had an iferror in place so i wasn't seeing that. so essentially what you said, but blanks instead of texts. thanks!